# all email addresses of file FileA is added to the group email called test@test.de

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I would like to modify the following script so that all email addresses of a column google drive file called **Finance** is added to the group email called test@test.de. How should I change the script?

```
function addToGroup() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var column = 7;
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, column, sheet.getLastRow())
  var email = range.getValue();

  Logger.log(email)
  addGroupMember(email, 'test@test.de')
}

function addGroupMember(userEmail, groupEmail) {
  var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: 'MEMBER'
  };

  AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);

}
```

I am receiving an error

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
```

and the error is

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheets" of null. (line 54, file "Code")

and the line 54 is

```
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
```

Comment: This may do better at [so].

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error, it means that the variable ss is null and that is very likely that occurred because the script isn't bounded to a spreadsheet.

One way to solve this error is to replace the following line

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

to something like

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
```

where id is the file ID of the spreadsheet.

Checkout  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet to learn other options.

Comment: Dear Ruben. greetings if the day. i replaced the whole code with this

Comment: @maherkhader: Do mean [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/113327/88163)?

Comment: yes it is the updated on